# Get the state of a table at a single point of time using timescaledb

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

Given the following data:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl;
CREATE TABLE tbl(date_time TIMESTAMPTZ, position TEXT);
INSERT INTO tbl(date_time, position)
VALUES
    ('2022-01-01 11:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'UP'),
    ('2022-01-01 13:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'LEFT'),
    ('2022-01-05 01:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'DOWN'),
    ('2022-01-08 10:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ, 'RIGHT')
;
```

I'd like to be able to determine what the position is for a particular point in time.

I've tried the following:

```sql
WITH tbl_state AS(
    SELECT 
        time_bucket('PT1M', date_time) as bucket,
        date_time,
        position,
        state_agg(date_time, position) as position_state
    FROM
        tbl
    GROUP BY 
        date_time,
        position
)
SELECT
    '2022-01-02 11:30'::TIMESTAMPTZ AS time_of_interest,
    state_at(position_state, '2022-01-02 11:30'::TIMESTAMPTZ) AS position_at_time
FROM
    tbl_state
order by 
    date_time
;
```

which gives:

```
    time_of_interest    │ position_at_time 
────────────────────────┼──────────────────
 2022-01-02 11:30:00+00 │ UP
 2022-01-02 11:30:00+00 │ LEFT
 2022-01-02 11:30:00+00 │ ∅
 2022-01-02 11:30:00+00 │ ∅
```

Where the answer I'm expecting is

```
    time_of_interest    │ position_at_time 
────────────────────────┼──────────────────
 2022-01-02 11:30:00+00 │ UP
```

If I change the query to (a timestamp after all entries in `tbl`):

```sql
SELECT
    '2022-01-09 13:30'::TIMESTAMPTZ AS time_of_interest,
    state_at(position_state, '2022-01-09 13:30'::TIMESTAMPTZ) AS position_at_time
FROM
    tbl_state
order by 
    date_time
```

Then I get:

```
    time_of_interest    │ position_at_time 
────────────────────────┼──────────────────
 2022-01-09 13:30:00+00 │ UP
 2022-01-09 13:30:00+00 │ LEFT
 2022-01-09 13:30:00+00 │ DOWN
 2022-01-09 13:30:00+00 │ RIGHT
```

Which is just giving me the original states, but overwriting the `date_time` column with the `2022-01-09` timestamp that I've given.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to not just limit and order the query?

```sql
 select position from tbl where date_time <= '2022-01-02 11:30'::TIMESTAMPTZ order by date_time desc limit 1;
┌──────────┐
│ position │
├──────────┤
│ LEFT     │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```